# I can't get data from firestore into textformfield

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
 ListTile(
               title: GetUsername(documentId: docIDs[index]),
                    trailing: GetGender(documentId: docIDs[index])),
                TextFormFieldWidget(
                  action: TextInputAction.next,
                  controller: controller,
                  hint: '${GetUsername(documentId: docIDs[index])}',
                  icon: Icons.abc,
                  obs: false,
                  read: true,
                )
```

[image]

I am trying to read data named username from Firestore. In the image, the 'asd' text seen in the upper left is the part that I created as an example and successfully retrieved the data. However, I wanted to show this data in a textformfield. I tried to call the hint property in String type and inside it in the widget named TextFormFieldWidget that I created. But I could not see the data that I successfully read in the upper left.

```
   final String documentId;
  const GetUsername({super.key, required this.documentId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text('${data['username']}');
        }
        return Text('Loading');
      },
    );
  }
```

GetUsername widget.

Comment: How you've define `controller`

Comment: final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the data you can use the controller to set test.

```dart
controller.text = "${data['username']}";
```